# “Massive” v.s. “Supermassive” black holes

Tags: black-holes, mass, event-horizon, order-of-magnitude

I *think* I understand what a black hole is. When there is enough mass in a given area the “bend” in time space approaches infinite (please correct me if this is wrong).
I understand there are different infinities (countable v.s. uncountable). So how do I make sense of a.. “standard” black hole v.s. a “supermassive” black hole. I thought the point of a black hole was “supermassive.” Is the difference “just” the diameter of the event horizon?

Comment: _Is the difference “just” the diameter of the event horizon?_ - Yes

Comment: Except not the diameter, but the circumference. The diameter of any black hole is zero (defined as the radial spacelike distance).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The supermassive black hole is simply a very massive black hole. The mass of the black hole is proportional to its horizon radius so they are also very big.

There is a class of "ordinary" black holes that are formed by collapsing heavy stars at the end of their evolution. The heaviest among them have masses that are less than hundred solar masses. They are properly called stellar mass black holes.

In contrast the masses of the supermassive black holes are larger than 100000 solar masses, many are much larger actually. There are few that may reach billions of solar masses! Those giants are usually situated near the center of the galaxies and their origin is caused by the collapse processes during the formation of galaxies.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between a massive and a supermassive blackhole is indeed the mass. Anything with a mass more than ~1.4 (correction - 2.5) solar masses (approximately because there are some LIGO observations that have not fully been classified yet) will become a blackhole after collapsing during its evolutionary period. Another pathway to make solar mass BH (colloquial term for ordinary BH) is to merge two neutron stars (this is the kind of thing LIGO can observe). The difference between solar mass BH and supermassive BH is that we don't know how exactly supermassive BH were formed.

As you can imagine it would take a long time to start with something that is a couple to a few hundred solar masses and grow it upto a million solar masses by just accreting material onto it and merging it with other BH. Formation of supermassive BH actually is a hot topic in astrophysics community right now, because we have seen supermassive BH observationally, and we have observed solar mass black holes using LIGO-Virgo, but we have not seen anything with mass more than a few hundred suns. This limits our ability to say how the jump from solar mass to supermassive BH is made - or if the formation of the two categories is even the same!

Comment: Your mass estimate for stellar black holes is a bit low. Neutron stars can exist upto ~2.5 solar masses, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tolman%E2%80%93Oppenheimer%E2%80%93Volkoff_limit#List_of_the_most_massive_neutron_stars And black holes progenitors are much more massive than that. Stars shed a lot of matter during the red giant phase, and a star needs to be quite massive to die in a core collapse supernova. During the supernova explosion, a lot of mass is (usually) ejected with great force, although some of that mass may fall back on the neutron star / black hole remnant.

Comment: Sorry, lol we were talking about the Chandrasekhar limit in my lectures today and somehow the number 1.4 stuck in my mind, thanks for pointing that out!